# How do I make a b2body polygon rotate around it's mass center?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, box2d, torque

This shouldn't be hard but I can't get it to work.

Basically, the user creates a b2body polygon by making lines on the screen.  I want that b2body to spin (or rotate around it's mass center).  I can do this with all the other shapes I make because their position is already set to their center.  But when I make a b2PolygonShape the position is set to 0,0.  Because the user is making the shape I can't be sure where it's mass center is.  And even if I did know I can't seem to rotate around it.  I tried ApplyAngularVelocity but the object spun around the origin (0,0).  I tried ApplyTorque and the object did absolutely nothing.  It just sat there.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

ApplyTorque or ApplyAngularImpulse should do it. Check that the body has a non-zero rotational inertia and is not set to be fixedRotation.
The center of mass can be found with GetWorldCenter().

Comment: I checked and my rotational inertia is 0.  That must be what's wrong.  How do I change that?

Comment: when you create a fixture, set the density to non-zero http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/fixtures